# Video Poker Probabilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games, poker

I developed a Video Poker software.
Its working fine "Jacks Or Better"

Now i want to improve it with statistics.I want the software to suggest which cards to hold to get the best possibility of a gain.

I know that holding $5$ cards in different way create $32$ scenarios.

What i want is to calculate the probability for each one of these $32$ scenarios :

1. Royal Flush
2. Straight Flush
3. Four Of A Kind
4. Full House
5. Flush
6. Straight
7. Three Of A Kind
8. Two Pairs
9. Jacks Or Better

I got the solution for Jacks or Better when nothing is hold ...

its: $13C1 * 4C2 * 12C3 * (4C1)^3 * \frac4{13}$

But whats the probability when my hand is

$JS - 2C - 6D - 7H - 10H$ and i hold $JS$.

Is it possible to develop a formula for each of $9$ ( Special Hands ) for a given scenario ?

When nothing is selected is easy.
But when you hold 1 , 2 or more cards depending what you want to achieve its very difficult for me ...

Please , i am struggling with it for a week and got formulas just when holding nothing ...

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You do know that in actual video poker machines, the odds are altered by non-uniform dealing, such that the casino can set the house percentage take wherever they want (within limits) just as on slot machines.

Comment: When nothing is selected (meaning, I assume, when the player discards all five cards and draws a ful new hand) the calculation is still not easy, because unless your machine cheats by re-using the discarded cards, the actual odds very slightly change depending on which five cards were discarded.